# Pinv not inverting my complex matrix entirely correct

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers

I have quite an extensive code so I'm not sure how I can share it and it be easy for you to read but my main question concerns the pinv function in numpy.linalg.
I am inverting a non-square complex matrix. Upon inverting I find myself with absolute values that are correct but the real or the complex (always one is incorrect but never both) values are negative when they need to be postive and vice-versa.
To resolve this I thought multiplying by -1 would have resolved the problem but as mentioned it's never both signs that are wrong. Does anyone have any idea why the pinv function would do this?

Comment: To address the problem of extensive code: [mre].

Comment: Thank you but this isn't the problem. I can't really reduce it much more

Comment: You claim *Pinv doesn't quite correctly invert my complex matrix* but can't provide a single example matrix to reproduce the problem?

Comment: We need to see a sample array that reproduces your problem.  We aren't interested in your extensive code.  How do you know the `pinv` is wrong.  You can't test it against `inv`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code about it without using `np.linalg.pinv`. it worked fine.

it is my code:

X and Y are my matrix

```
Xt = np.transpose(X)
X1 = np.matmul(Xt,X)
X2 = np.matmul(X,Xt)
try:
      Xinv = np.linalg.inv(X1)
      W = np.matmul(Xinv,Xt)
      print("1")
except:
      Xinv = np.linalg.inv(X2)
      W = np.matmul(Xt,Xinv)
      print("2")
#W = np.linalg.pinv(X,rcond=1e-5)
W = np.matmul(W,Y)
```